# Функция words из Data.List

Tags: функции, haskell, функциональное-программирование

В данный момент читаю книгу Learn You a Haskell for Great Good. В главе про модули, наткнулся на функцию words из Data.List.

Возник вопрос:
 В чем ее отличие от функции words из стандартной библиотеки Prelude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отличия нет. Это одна и та же функция, просто экспортированная из разных модулей.

Haskell позволяет так делать: импортировать функции из одного модуля и переэкспортировать из другого, как-то вот так:

```
module MyModule (words) where

import Data.List (words)

...
```